# Numpy, multiply dataframe by number outputting NaN

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I am trying to multiply dataframe 1 column a by dataframe 2 column b.

```
combineQueryandBookFiltered['pnlValue'] = np.multiply(combineQueryandBookFiltered['pnlValue'], df_fxrate['fx_rate'])
```

pnlValue column has many numbers and fx_rate column is just the one number.

The code executes but my end result ends up with tons of `NaN` .

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: check the index of your dataframe...

Comment: What do you mean? Can you explain why

Comment: when you multiply two series the values ​​of the series are multiplied according to the index of the series. Therefore, if the dataframes have different indexes then the series will also have it and the result will be NaN.

Comment: Tell me if I am right. And if you can evaluate my answer

Answer (score 4):

It is probably due to the index of your dataframe. You need to use  `df_fxrate['fx_rate'].values`:

```
combineQueryandBookFiltered['pnlValue'] = np.multiply(combineQueryandBookFiltered['pnlValue'], df_fxrate['fx_rate'].values)
```

**or better:**

```
combineQueryandBookFiltered['pnlValue']=combineQueryandBookFiltered['pnlValue']*df_fxrate['fx_rate'].values
```

---

I show you an example:

```
df1=pd.DataFrame(index=[1, 2])
df2=pd.DataFrame(index=[0])
df1['col1']=[1,1]
print(df1)

 col1
1     1
2     1
```

---

```
df2['col1']=[1]
print(df2)

   col1
0     1
```

---

```
print(np.multiply(df1['col1'],df2['col1']))

0   NaN
1   NaN
2   NaN
```

**as you can see the multiplication is done according to the index**

> So you need something like this:

```
np.multiply(df1['col1'],df2['col1'].values)
```

or

```
df1['col1']*df2['col1'].values
```

**Output:**

```
1    1
2    1
Name: 1, dtype: int64
```

**as you can see now only the df1['col1'] series index is used**

Answer (score 3):

-- Hi excelguy,

Is there a reason why you can't use the simple column multiplication?

```
df['C'] = df['A'] * df['B']
```

As was pointed out, multiplications of two series are based on their indices and it's likely that your fx_rate series does not have the same indices as the pnlValue series.

But since your fx_rate is only one value, I suggest multiplying your dataframe with a scalar instead:

```
fx_rate = df_fxrate['fx_rate'].iloc[0]
combineQueryandBookFiltered['pnlValue'] = combineQueryandBookFiltered['pnlValue'] * fx_rate
```

Comment: With your recommendation I am still getting the 'NaN' issue in the column `pnlValue`

Comment: @excelguy Could you provide more info on the dataframe itself? Ideally a sample of the data so I can reproduce your error?

Comment: @excelguy updated my answer after realising your columns originate from different dataframes. Let me know if this works.

Comment: if its value is contained in a series you do not need to extract the value of the series

Comment: @ansev updated to extract first value from series assuming all are the same.